# Safe to delete C:\inetpub?

Tags: windows-7

I recently noticed the C:\inetpub folder on my laptop running Windows 7.  I disabled Internet Information Services under windows services, but after rebooting, some of the options under that service were automatically turned back on.  I don't have a web site, but okay.

What bothers me is that inetpub should not have been installed on my C: drive and should be somewhere in the Windows system folders, right?

So can I safely delete the c:\inetpub folder ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614356/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-inetpub-folder) is related

Comment: As for why it's there even if you don't have IIS installed, it could be from having the Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation feature turned on.  To check, go to Control Panel | Programs and Features, then click on "Turn Windows features on or off" on the left.  In the Windows Features dialog, expand Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1.  Leave .NET Framework checked if you need it, but you can uncheck the two sub-features.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  I unchecked the .NET Framework sub-features and deleted C:\inetpub.  After reboot, all seems okay.

Answer (score 2):

> So can I safely delete the c:\inetpub folder ?

The folder contains no system files.  If you want to delete it, feel free, just be sure to verify it contains nothing you actually want to keep.  I should point out that, unless you disable IIS and/or reconfigure IIS, IIS will simply create the folder again.

What you should do instead is modify the contents of 
`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config` and simply make the required modifications so the desired path is used instead.

Source: [Is it safe to delete the “InetPub” folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614356/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-inetpub-folder)

Comment: Thank you Ramhound.  I opened applicationhost.config and did not understand what I saw.  If IIS creates the folder again I will learn how to use the Manager to change the path.